# Can I use a token in Headers in Swift to authorisation a database connection?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, security

I am looking to add some security to my app. My train of thought is:

I add a token, `base64LoginString` to my app which is sent in the header  of my connection/JSON request.

Do I then need to also add this same token into my PHP scripts / pre-database connection so that before any connection to the database is made it looks to see if the token in the php connection matches that in the header of my Swift script?

I am totally new to security and really just trying to figure out where to start.

```
let username = "user"
let password = "pass"
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

let myUrl = URL(string: "https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyApp/userLogin.php");
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

request.httpMethod = "POST";
let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
```

So with the code above, my hope is that token is currently been sent...

1) Is this true?

2) How do I check and validate this on my server-side connection?

3) If this is not correct, what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is this true?

The token is being sent, and in your code you are replicating the HttpMethod

> 2) How do I check and validate this on my server-side connection?

If the server is Linux, you can use tcpdump to check the entry connection to the server. Something like this

```
tcpdump -i any tcp port 80 -w capture.cap
```

This command will capture all packages coming on the 80 port and save it to the capture.cap file. Then with the command

```
strings capture.cap
```

You can check the entry connection of your test.

And if the server is Windows you can approach the same by using Wireshark, and also capturing 80 port packets.

> 3) If this is not correct, what would be a better approach?

I recommend using Alamofire, It's a pod that saves you a lot of time in http requests. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire